# Prevent a user with a valid session to directly access a json feed

Tags: php

I am using fullcalendar to fetch a json feed (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed).

```javascript
<script>
var calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
  events: '/myfeed.php'
}); 
</script>
```

Here, I am fetching events from a google calendar.

```php
<?php
$api_key = 'xxx';
$calendar_id = 'xxx';

$url = "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/$calendar_id/events?key=$api_key";
$response = file_get_contents($url);
$events = json_decode($response, true);

$formatted_events = array();
foreach ($events['items'] as $event) {
$formatted_events[] = array(
'title' => $event['summary'],
'start' => $event['start']['dateTime'] ?? $event['start']['date'],
'end' => $event['end']['dateTime'] ?? $event['end']['date']
);
}
echo json_encode($formatted_events);
?>
```

When typing the address of `<myserver>/myfeed.php` in the address bar, one can also directly access the json elements.

```
[{"title":"title1","start":"2023-09-01T10:30:00+02:00","end":"2023-09-01T12:30:00+02:00"},{"title":"title2","start":"2023-09-01T14:30:00+02:00","end":"2023-09-01T16:30:00+02:00"}]
```

As this feed is in a private part of the website, it is easy to prevent anyone to access the feed (e.g. using `isset($_SESSION['user']` in `myfeed.php`).

But **how can I prevent a user with a valid session to directly type the address of my.feed.php and then access the feed** ?

I thought I could place `myfeed.php` above the `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` but I guess it is not 'safe' to allow a js code (see above) to access a file above the `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`.

Best

**EDIT**

using

```php
<?php
$postedUrl = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if ( $postedUrl !='/admin/myfeed') {
// fetch events 
}
?>
```

in `myfeed.php` seems working. But is this secure enough ?

Comment: You're trying to stop users from accessing content you want the users to access. Give up. It doesn't work. The user can trivially bypass any restrictions you place, and it's trivial to see in the developer console.

Comment: Yes ... you are right ....

Comment: At least what I do prevent the user to access the complete calendar (e.g. between 2022 and 2023) as the display (and so the response) show events for a week maximum.

Comment: Change the backend to only send a week into the future.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that you shouldn't try.

Yes, there are things you can do, but they will be complex and fragile. One obvious solution is to set a time-limited, single use token in the server-side session when a user access a page which should be permit access to the calendar.

> it is not 'safe' to allow a js code (see above) to access a file above the $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']

I have no idea what you are saying here. It is impossible to access content directly outside the document root (which includes mappings to paths elsewhere).

> But is this secure enough ?

1. I have no idea how this enforces your constraint
2. We don't know how much security you actually want in this scenario

Comment: Thanks. Apologies if I was not clear. With the above solution (see Edit), a user see a blank page when typing the address of myfeed but FullCalendar still can access the feed.